# WCF - keep custom data after authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, session

I use custom user name/password validator. And I have to create special object that depends on username/password. This object will be used futher in service. Validator looks like:

```
public class CustomUserNamePasswordValidator: UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        try
        {
            var session = new Session(userName, password);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenException("Unknown Username or Password");
        }
    }
}
```

Session is my own type. I try to provide web access to another API via web-services. Think that every API calling should be provided with session object.
Can I keep my session object for using them in service methods? This object should be defferent for every service instance (per call or per session). What is the best way to do it in case of Session type implements IDisposable?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. If You want to have your session object for every instance of WCF service, you can create this session object in constructor of WCF service. Each method will have access to session object via instance field and each method will have access to username via OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name property. Of course, methods will not have access to password.

Comment: But I can't to get password inside WCF Service instance. So, I can't to create MySession object.
I did it followed way. WCF service has public static dictionary with login/passwords. CustomValidator stores login/password int this dictionary. WCF Service creates (in constructor) MySession object with using the dictionary and OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name (or similar). But this way smells. 1) I forced to create two MySession objects - in validator and in service. 2) I store passwords in memory - security issue. Plus passwords can be changed.